# 'test/spec/**/*.' + jsExt in Yeoman generator-angular

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, angularjs-e2e, yeoman-generator-angular

Hi I just have a question:

What exactly does 'test/mock/**/*.' + jsExt do?

I know 'test/spec/**/*.' + jsExt is to unit test controllers.

I thought this was for e2e test but I learned it is not integrated yet.

It might be better if we include a sample file in test/spec/ folder?

Also this might be a silly question. Since there is no e2e integrated, why does the generator include 'angular-scenario' by default? Is it just for people who want to add e2e test in their project?

Thank you.

commit log is 
https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/commit/0f768f1d7515b3d884555a8c5c8e3f01d117cf18#commitcomment-6826108

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you put your mocks.

So for example, let's say you typically make a `$http` call to get a value from the server.  During unit testing you don't want to do this, you want to mock this out.

You can do that with the `$q` library and return a 'mocked' value.  Then instead of injecting the service that has the `$http` call, you would inject the server that uses `$q` and returns the mocked value.

Hope this helps.